# Groovy XMLSlurper namespace error without namespaces

Tags: grails, groovy, xmlslurper

I have following XML that XMLSlurper is unable to parse. I think XMLSlurper thinks the xxx:yyy is some kind of namespace. Is there any chance to change this behavior?

```
<node>
  <application app_name="export" 
               app_data="nolocal:api_on_answer=sched_hangup +3600 40887ffe-65de-11e1-89da-e9feb0a98acf alloted_timeout" 
               app_stamp="1330854103808996">
  </application>
</node>
```

I cannot change the XML.
The error i get:

```
The prefix "nolocal" for element "nolocal:api_on_answer" is not bound.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: The prefix "nolocal" for element "nolocal:api_on_answer" is not bound.
Line | Method
->>   48 | doCall    in sipsy.admin.WebapiController$_closure4$$ENQh9JnT
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this problem using Groovy 1.8.5. What version are you using ?

Comment: Sry, my fault (as usual :D). I've worked with the wrong data. There are 2 xml strings, the one i've posted and a similiar one, with a <nolocal:api_on_answer> tag. shame on me...

thank you for your time :)

Comment: Just to be complete: If you need to parse not 100% valid XML, you can pass 2 booleans to the constructor of XmlSlurper(a, b). A is for validation and b for namespace awareness.

Comment: @thelittlebug - if this solved your problem, please either mark the question answered, or remove it.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek - how can i mark the question as answered?

Comment: You should be able to post an answer to your question, and then accept it. This will also help people looking for the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my fault (as usual :D). I've worked with the wrong data. There are 2 xml strings, the one i've posted and a similiar one, with a  tag. shame on me... thank you for your time :)

Just to be complete: If you need to parse not 100% valid XML, you can pass 2 booleans to the constructor of XmlSlurper(a, b). A is for validation and b for namespace awareness.